# How to auto-implement interfaces with single line properties in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, formatting

I am following tutorials by Tim Corey on C#. When he auto-implements an interface (with ctr + .) all the properties are on single lines, like this:

```
    public class MyModel : IMyInterface
{
    public string example1 { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public string example2 { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

But when I do the same I get this:

```
    public class MyModel : IMyInterface
{
    public string example1
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public string example2 { get; set; }
            {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

It would be nice to make my code look the same as the instructor so it's easier to follow the tutorials, also I think the second format looks quite rowdy.

Is there a preference setting somewhere I can set so I get the properties (if that's what they are called) on single lines?

I have tried to look for duplicates but since I am quite new and not sure about the C# vernacular it's not that easy.

Comment: Is it possible that you are using tools like ReSharper. They will hook into source code generation and apply their custom formatting. If so, disable ReSharper and try again. If this should fix it you need to do some adjustements in ReSharper code generation.

Comment: You can do that with JetBrains Resharper

Comment: @Dainiel I am not using resharper, but maybe the instructor is. I will look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That’s a c# 6 feature - [expression bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#property-get-statements)

Make sure you [enable c# 6 features in VS2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/12/07/new-feature-to-enable-c-6-vb-14/).

Comment: Hi. The project I'm doing currently is a console application. The option to enable C#6 did not show up. I tried to make a new Web Application project, and there it showed up in the project menu. Is there a way to enable it in console applications?